# Why does C++ operator<< in ifstream omit certain data?

Tags: c++, std, fstream

In the code below, I have a collection of binary files that are created from downloading parts of an iso file. Individually they are just a collection of bytes with no semantics of their own. I wish to merge them into one file, back to the original iso. Since all the individual files are just binaries, I passed in `std::ios_base::binary` in both `std::ifstream` and `std::ofstream`. However, it seems `operator<<` in `std::ifstream` still does some formatting or locale configuration even when opening it in binary mode. In my particular case, more than 3000 bytes are missing from the output.iso, yet if I use linux `cat` to merge them, the size is correct and a real iso file is formed. The files I used are 12 parts of an iso each consisting of roughly 160 MiB, so it's unsuitable to upload them all here.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  vector<ifstream> files; // assume all the streams are created correctly,
                          //  std::ios_base::binary is passed in

  ofstream out{"output.iso", std::ios_base::binary | std::ios_base::trunc |
                                 std::ios_base::ate};
  for (auto const &file : files) {
    out << file.rdbuf();
  }

  // the size of the output.iso is not the size of all the individual files combined
  // when using the linux cat command to merge all files together, it works as
  // expected with the size of the output binary equal to the size of all
  // individual files combined
}
```

Comment: There is nothing obviously wrong with the shown code, therefore the problem, if there is any, must be with the code that's not shown, and it is unlikely that anyone will be able to tell you what would be the problem with code that's not even shown, including the claimed assumption that "all the streams are created correctly". You are right that posting 160mb worth of binary goop here is "unsuitable"; but unless you can come up with something that meets the requirements for a [mre], that anyone can copy/paste, run, and reproduce your problem, noone wlil be able to help you.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I did some experiments after posting the question, the issue is when the `ifstream`s are created and written to, I did not flush them when done. Meaning when it's time to append them, the rdbuf pointer is not in sync with the actual content. I apologize for the insufficient information and the lack of resource files. However, I hope anybody in the future experiencing similar issue can see this comment and see if they need to flush the stream.

Comment: Can you explain how you managed to write to an input-only stream?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik The file was created and written to from another thread, then a sperate thread waited for the completion of the write thread before attempting to merge them, obviously joining the thread in my case did not mean the buffer was flushed.